# Manually handle transactions instead of JtaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-transactions

I am working on a setup with multiple databases, technology stack's spring with hibernate running on tomcat 6. Transactions across databases was not a requirement, and each database has its own dataSource, sessionFactory and transactionManager (org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager) with a declarative use of transaction management (@Transactional annotation). Recently there have been a requirement to have a one-off case of making insertions in two of those DBs (say db1 and db2) transactional.

I am aware that there are third party libraries like JOTM and atomikos, which can add JTA support to tomcat. But I would like to know if it's at all possible to manage transactions manually.

For example, can there be something like following?

```
Transaction transactionDb1 =     sessionFactoryDb1.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
Transaction transactionDb2 = sessionFactoryDb2.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
try
{
    // DAO layer call to DB1
    // DAO layer call to DB2

    transactionDb1.commit();
    transactionDb2.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    transactionDb1.rollback();
    transactionDb2.rollback();
}
```

It probably wouldn't be as simplistic. But is something like that possible? As far as I know Programmatic transactional handling can be used. But how do I go about it combining with the declarative approach? Would I still be able to use @Transactional for other cases? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: so, you want to separate out the transactions of the two databases? Even if one fails, the other one should commit?

Comment: Actually no. Ideally the code should be something if this effect
if(transactionDb1.wasCommitted()) transactionDb2.commit()
else //rollback both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use programmatic transaction against multiple non-JTA DataSources, but there won't be any global transaction. Each DataSource will use its own isolated transaction, so if the first one commits and the second one rollbacks, you won't have a chance to roll back the already committed first transactions.

The [Spring @Transactional annotation](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) can only target one TransactionManager only, and since you don's use JTA, you can either pick one SessionFactory or DataSource. That's why you can only rely on `JtaTransactionManager`, if you want automatic transaction management. If you don't want JTA, you will have to write your own transaction management code.

Comment: Ah...well..that's what I thought. Kind of no (easier) way without JTA. Thanks.